# Cannot Enter MOK Enroll Password, seems keyboard isn't working

Tags: 20.04, secure-boot

Linux installed with Secure Boot enabled, but cannot Enter password in the MOK Enroll screen, seems keyboard isn't working.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo0Gd.jpg)

Comment: No, it gives no feedback by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 'by design' - the password is still being accepted even though you are not getting any feedback from typing.  Type your password and then hit enter and proceed through the MOK prompts.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue before understanding that I have to type only the character that it ask me.
Example, if my password is "password1234" and it ask me "Enter password character 2", I have to type only "a". After few askings, it unlocks.